# how to put angular files in express server?

Tags: angular, express

how to put angular files in express server?

i searched for this and i didn't find the answer, my problem is that my friend have created some web pages with angular and i made express server i want to know how to put the angular files in my express server, i have tried to view projects in github but i didn't get how they did it
one more thing i want to do this without using the angular server

and please someone help me, don't that i have done anything wrong or something with what i said

how can i do this ?

Comment: If you're not doing anything like server-side rendering, using Express just to serve the Angular files is probably slightly overkill...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be overkill to use Express just to serve static files.

That said, if you really want to:

1) Build the angular project (using ng build if you have angular-cli installed)

2) Copy the resulting `dist` directory into your express app

3) Add

```
app.use(express.static('dist'))
```

into your express app, where `dist` is the path to the directory you just copied

4) You should now be able to load `index.html` from your express app, and see your angular app:

```
http://localhost:3000/index.html
```

Comment: what should i do if it's not a static files?

Comment: What do you mean? Once an angular app is built, it will always be a series of static files...